# C++ ints getting corrupted, generated with rand()

Tags: c++, random

I'm attempting to write a C++ program that uses a Point class consisting of x and y coordinates (ints) and a boolean. The x and y coordinates should be in the range from 0-100, but upon execution and with a print statement to test, the values printed out are corrupted.

My code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
vector<Point> points;

for (int i = 0; i<200; i++) {
    int rand_X = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    int rand_Y = (rand() & 100) + 1;

    Point point = Point(rand_X, rand_Y, false);
    cout<< point.getX() << " " << point.getY() << endl;
    points.push_back(point);
}

return 0;
```

and the Point class looks like this, if that's relevant:

```
struct Point { 
public:

    int x;

    int y;

    bool in_layer;

    Point(int x, int y, bool in_layer) {}
    int getX() {return this->x;}
    int getY() {return this->y;}
};
```

And the output is just "-272632592 32766" repeated 200 times, which I'm assuming is a corrupted value.

Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Your C++ book should have many examples of constructors that initialize members of the class from their parameters. Can you look at some of these examples, and spot a major difference between those examples, and your constructor? Can you show some of these examples from your C++ book?

Comment: Fixed! Thank you. I just needed to create a custom constructor instead of the default.

New Point constructor now looks like: 

Point(int x_coord, int y_coord, bool layer) {x = x_coord; y = y_coord; layer = in_layer;}

Comment: @ausar999: You generally want *initializers*, not just assignment in the constructor body. `Point(int x_coord, int y_coord, bool layer) : x(x_coord), y(y_coord), in_layer(layer) {}`; it gets the same result, but performs direct initialization instead of default initializing, then reassigning.

Comment: @ausar999 And is this line you wrote a typo?`int rand_Y = (rand() & 100) + 1;`

Comment: another suggestion, avoid using `std::rand`, use `<random>` instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `Point point = Point(rand_X, rand_Y, false);` is usually written, more simply, as `Point point(rand_X, rand_Y, false);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor didn't do anything, which contribute to an UB when you call `getX` `getY` methods. Plus, I think there's no need to use constructor and `getx` `gety` methods here.

If that's a code for learning, you may need to assign to the member `x, y` in the constructor or use the folowing technique (initialization list):

```
Point(int _x, int _y, bool _in_layer) : x(_x),  y(_y), in_layer(_in_layer){}
```

Comment: As a suggestion, I think you should remove all your mothods and use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) if you are doing practical work